# Cannot override a method because of a name clash

Tags: java, generics, name-clash

This code doesn't compile:

```
import java.util.List;

class A {
  void foo(List l) { }
}

class B extends A {
  void foo(List<?> l) { }
}
```

However, the following code compiles (foo in D overrides foo in C). Why?

```
class C {
  void foo(List<?> l) { }
}

class D extends C {
  void foo(List l) { }
}
```

Comment: Please post the compile error - it'll make the question easier to answer.

Comment: OK here is the message: name clash foo(java.util.List<?>) in B and foo(java.util.List) in A have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other.

Answer (score 2):

The second example compiles because List<> derives from List, but not the other way around which is why the first example doesn't compile.

Comment: That's not true in general: String extends Object (but not the other way around), yet the first example would compile.

Comment: @Gmacar - I don't see the word String or Object in the two examples.

Comment: It was a new example, based on your answer.